# VBA syntax to find an if conditional statement field code

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am searching for the correct syntax for my macro to find an IF Conditional statement field code.

I need to search for `{IF{DOCVARIABLE"CODE"} = "YES" "A" "B"}` to remove this and replace with "B" (the false statement).

When searching for a word field like `{DOCVARIABLE "CODE"}` alone, I write as: `Text1 = "CODE"` but when there is an IF & Text & Yes & TRUE, FALSE like above, how do I write?

Comment: looks like you cross-posted in http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/worddev/thread/ac44c87d-c5c1-4b4a-9a54-c6798b7cc30f

Answer (score 0):

Consolidated comment (OP crossposted elsewhere):

For that specific sequence, you can search for

```
^19IF^19DOCVARIABLE"CODE"
```

Word will select the entire IF field (so you will then need to parse the entire IF field anyway), but it should not select e.g.

```
{IF{DOCVARIABLE"BOX"}
```

If there is some variation (e.g. additional whitespace in the string) you may be able to use something like

```
^19^wIF^w^19^wDOCVARIABLE^w"CODE"
```