# Find all instances of "{ XE text text }" with RegEx

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm working on a macro that will loop through my Word document, and select all of the XE codes, to parse through.

I'm trying to use `Find` to get all such texts, but my regex searches aren't working at all.

I've tried: `</{ XE*/}>`, `<{*XE*}>` to no avail.

To remind, the text will look like this:

```
{ XE "Superhero - means a person with some powers" }
{ XE "Mountain is a tall hill, not always climbable." }
{ XE "Hill is a smaller mountain; not always large." }
```

I want to loop through each of these, and add two characters after each `;`found.  How can I find these using RegEx?

Edit: For some reason, the `.Find` never executes, even with the below code:

```
Sub escape_Special_Characters_in_XE_Text()
Dim regExSearch$
Dim doc     As Word.Document
Dim rngDoc As Word.Range, rngXE As Word.Range, rng As Word.Range
Dim bFound  As Boolean
Dim iFieldCodeBegin&

Set doc = ActiveDocument
Set rngDoc = doc.Content
Set rngXE = rngDoc.Duplicate
bFound = True
iFieldCodeBegin = 6          '?
rngDoc.Find.ClearFormatting
With rngDoc.Find
        .Text = "^d XE"
        '.Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With

rngDoc.Find.Execute
rngDoc.Select ' This selects the whole document for some reason?

End Sub
```

Is there something I'm overlooking with regard to my Document? Why can't it find anything.  If I record a macro, it uses `Selection` instead of a variable, but I can run that over and over.  When I try to use variables is when it seems to disagree with me.

Comment: The special field code braces "{ }" aren't findable using the regular characters {} and ms-word/word-vba do not themselves implement RegEx in the modern sense of the word. See, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14547866/vba-syntax-to-find-an-if-conditional-statement-field-code/36209603#36209603

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, you can find the starting braces of a field code using Word's Find by specifying the ESC combination: `^d`

And when Find picks up the starting point of a field, the entire field is included in the Selection/Range. So you can loop all the XE fields in a document along the following lines:

```
Sub LoopAllXE()
    Dim doc As word.Document
    Dim rngDoc As word.Range
    Dim rngXE As word.Range
    Dim bFound As Boolean
    Dim iFieldCodeBegin As Long

    'Initialization
    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    Set rngDoc = doc.content
    Set rngXE = rngDoc.Duplicate
    bFound = True
    iFieldCodeBegin = 6
    With rngDoc.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .ClearAllFuzzyOptions
        .Text = "^d XE"
        .Format = False
        .wrap = wdFindStop
    End With

    'Get the XE fields' content
    Do While bFound
        bFound = rngDoc.Find.Execute
        If bFound Then
            Set rngXE = rngDoc.Duplicate
            'Do something with the XE field content
            'Below, the content is being trimmed of field code info
            Debug.Print Mid(rngXE.Text, iFieldCodeBegin, _
                            Len(rngXE) - iFieldCodeBegin - 1)
            'Content in table cells needs to be processed differently
            'in order to avoid looping endlessly on the first "found"
            Do While rngDoc.Information(wdWithInTable) And bFound
                rngDoc.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
                'Remainder of cell content after XE-field
                rngDoc.End = rngDoc.Cells(1).Range.End - 1
                bFound = rngDoc.Find.Execute
                Set rngXE = rngDoc.Duplicate
                'Do something with the XE field content
                'May make sense to put this in a separate procedure
                Debug.Print Mid(rngXE.Text, iFieldCodeBegin, _
                            Len(rngXE) - iFieldCodeBegin - 1)
                If Not bFound Then
                    rngDoc.MoveStart wdCell, 1
                End If
            Loop
            rngDoc.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
            rngDoc.End = doc.content.End
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: I created the most simple doc. ever, added an XE code (note: which is visible regardless if I have 'hidden text' (the backwards P symbol thing) off). Then the simple code I have above works.  Unfortunately, I can't really share my "live" document as it's confidental, but I will try to get a parsed down copy that I can share (I really appreciate your offer to help!).  Also, it still randomly will decide to loop through the same `.Find` part.  Also, FYI I have a bunch of Styles in the document, would that hinder this?

Comment: Sorry, final question - now that I can grab the text of the Field (with your `Mid()` formula, I've saved that to a String variable (`foundText = Mid(rngXE.text, iFieldCodeBegin, ...)`).  Where in the code would I loop through that to remove any semicolons, then "reset" the field text to be this new, semicolon-less, text?  I'd do this in the section after you put "Do something with the XE Field Content..."?

Comment: Use the REPLACE function to get rid of the semicolons - no need for a loop! There are two places in my code for that: one in the "main loop", the other in the section that handles tables, which is why I remark you might want to put that code in a different procedure, so you don't have to write it twice. "Resetting" field content can be tricky - if you run into problems please post a new question. I'll be marking some of this comments discussion for removal, since the problems no longer repro...

Comment: Thanks @CindyMeister !!! :D :D (I used `editedDefinition = Replace(editedDefinition, ";", "")`  just before adding to the index.  You're a great help, I hope you have a nice weekend!